# Can less be instructed to collapse blocks of lines

Tags: less

Is there a way to instruct `less` to fold blocks of lines matching some criteria into a single line in the view?

For example while viewing a mail spool with `less`, the mail headers may take up a lot of screen area, which could have been used to display more mail content. It would be convenient for me, if I could somehow tell it to fold all the `Received` headers and display only the first line of each.

I considered sending the file through a filter and pipe that to `less`, however there are three drawbacks to that approach: It is slower to get to the end of the file, I cannot open/close the folded blocks without quitting and starting over, I cannot see new data being appended to the file, while it is open.

In case it makes any difference, the system I would be using this on is running Debian.

Comment: I think both `vim` and `emacs` for example can do this. I don't think `less` or any other pager can (though I could be wrong). Personally I would just use `emacs` or `vim` or something similar, but open the file in read-only mode. Btw, if you are not already familiar with the `most` pager, you might want to check it out. It allows you to open multiple windows for example.

Comment: @FaheemMitha If I were to use an editor, I would still have to wait for them to load the entire file. And I would also not see new data as it is appended to the file.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Maybe add a wishlist bug for less?

Comment: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html. I don't see anything about folding there.

Comment: Pipe a command that does the folding to `less`. E.g. `grep -v Received: filename | less`

Comment: @Barmar My question mentioned three reasons why piping a command doesn't fit my needs. And your example command doesn't actually remove the correct lines.

Comment: It was just an example. You need to pipe something that does remove the correct lines. I don't think there's any way to get the dynamic behavior that you want, it would have to be built into `less`, and it isn't.